# Custom Flexigrid table with filter bars below the column headers

Tags: jquery, flexigrid

Can anyone please let me know how can I add a custom filter bars just below the column headers  in flexigrid table. I need a filter bar which is a combination of textfield and drop down arrow.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct way to do that.

But you can acheive by a `hidden column`

1)Take a Column

2)Assign your Field value there

3)Give width zero

4)Then set that as sortable,So it will appear in all `columns
    filter`

It looks like :

```
{ display: 'Some X', name : 'sortFieldname', width : 0, 
                                           sortable : true, align: 'center'}
```